# How to represent inverse trig function as another inverse trig function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, trigonometry

I'm struggling with this one. How can I respesent some inverse function as another inverse function? Is it possible to represent let's say $\arctan(-2)$ in terms of $\arccos(...)$, $\arcsin(...)$, $\text{arccot(...)}$?

**Specific examples:**

$\arctan{(-2)}$ respresented as $\arccos$

$\arcsin{(-\frac{3}{4}})$ respresented as $\arctan$

$\arctan{(-3)}$ represented as $\arcsin$

I suppose it has to do something with the right triangle, and this is the part that I'm struggling with. I do know how to apply trigonometric functions to the right triangle thing, but no idea how to do it with inverse ones.

Thank you!

Comment: You might draw a triangle, then everything would be easier.

Comment: Not sure how to apply inverse functions to the triangle.

Comment: No, i mean draw a triangle to figure out what angle those inverse trig function represent. E.g. $\arctan (-2)$ is an angle whose tangent is $-2$, then it should represent an angle $A $ in a right triangle with the opposed side $-2$ and the adjacent side $1$. Then $\cos A$ = adjacent / hypotenuse = $1/\sqrt 5$, so it should be $\arccos (1/\sqrt 5)$ or something. **However the image [or, range] of** $\arccos, \arctan$ **are different, so you may not be able to do so**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [these identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) useful

[image]